# How to get the root element with XPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xpath

Here is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
   <rootfiles>
        <rootfile full-path="content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
    </rootfiles>
</container>
```

All I want to do is get the root file element. I'm using TouchXML on the iPhone and here is my xPath query:

```
/container/rootfiles/rootfile
```

It doesn't work! I've tried everything.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for pointers and also for a pure XPath solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `xmlns` bit within the `container` node is a namespace prefix that you may have your query register.

I don't know TouchXML well enough to say what the solution is, but the relevant `libxml2` call is [`xmlXPathRegisterNs()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpathInternals.html#xmlXPathRegisterNs) if you go into the innards of TouchXML.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526887/getting-the-value-of-an-element-in-cocoa-using-touchxml/526920#526920) might also help point you to the right TouchXML method to use to register this namespace.

Comment: dude, I think you're right on. Apparently touch xml has some problems
that are know with xPath. I'm gonna try to fix them! Who knows, maybe someone will benefit?

Comment: That's a nice thing about open source. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**I am not a specialist in TouchXML, but [this](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/issues/detail?id=4) may help you.**

**There is also a somewhat ugly pure XPath solution**.

Use:

```
/*[name()='container']/*[name()='rootfiles']/*[name()='rootfile']
```