# CXMLDocument - [CXMLNode nodeForXPath] problem?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing

I'm developing epub reader program.

To get contents of the epub file, I wanted to parse container.xml.

Here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
    <rootfiles>
    <rootfile full-path="OPS/content.opf"
  media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
</rootfiles>
</container>
```

I wanted to get  element, so I used following code.

```
CXMLDocument* manifestFile = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:manifestFilePath] options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

NSArray* nodes = [manifestFile nodesForXPath:@"//rootfiles" error:nil];
NSLog(@"Nodes count is %d\n", [nodes count]);
```

And I get the following result.

```
Nodes count is 0
```

Why do I got this result?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what is `CXMLDocument` but may be you should call in such manner `NSArray* nodes = [manifestFile nodesForXPath:@"rootfiles" error:nil];`?

Comment: CXMLDocument is TouchXML library for parsing xml files. You can find this in https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The problem is that your XML has a namespace.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526887/getting-the-value-of-an-element-in-cocoa-using-touchxml) You need to explicitly define the namespaces to use when querying with XPath.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container",
                      @"oasis", 
                      nil];

NSArray* nodes = [manifestFile nodesForXPath:@"//oasis:rootfiles" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];

NSLog(@"Nodes count is %d\n", [nodes count]); // --> Nodes count is 1
```