# iOS CXMLElement StringValue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parsing, touchxml

I'm trying to parse an xml here and am getting my CXMLElement properly. One, for example, logs this

```
<CXMLElement 0x1d8cfdc0 [0x1c556660] TrackDetail <TrackDetail>Tracked</TrackDetail>>
```

but I can't get the string value, in this case `Tracked`. I've tried

```
CXMLNode *title = [[fd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nodeForXPath:@"TrackDetail" error:nil];
```

but logging this returns `null`. Anyone know how to get the stringValue of a CXMLElement?

Heres the example xml

```
<TrackResponse>
 <TrackInfo ID="9400110200793563195827">
  <TrackSummary>
  The delivery status for this item has not been updated as of February 07, 2013, 11:34 pm.
  </TrackSummary>
  <TrackDetail>
  Out for Delivery, February 07, 2013, 9:34 am, MASSAPEQUA, NY 11758
  </TrackDetail>
  <TrackDetail>
  Sorting Complete, February 07, 2013, 9:24 am, MASSAPEQUA, NY 11758
  </TrackDetail>
  <TrackDetail>
  Arrival at Post Office, February 07, 2013, 6:00 am, MASSAPEQUA, NY 11758
  </TrackDetail>
  <TrackDetail>
  Depart USPS Sort Facility, February 05, 2013, GRAND FORKS, ND 58201
  </TrackDetail>
  <TrackDetail>
  Processed at USPS Origin Sort Facility, February 04, 2013, 7:13 pm, GRAND FORKS, ND 58201
  </TrackDetail>
  <TrackDetail>
  Accepted at USPS Origin Sort Facility, February 04, 2013, 5:58 pm, EAST GRAND FORKS, MN 56721
  </TrackDetail>
  <TrackDetail>
  Electronic Shipping Info Received, February 04, 2013
  </TrackDetail>
  <TrackDetail>
  Shipment Accepted, February 04, 2013, 2:19 pm, EAST GRAND FORKS, MN 56721
  </TrackDetail>
 </TrackInfo>
</TrackResponse>
```

and I parse it using this

```
NSArray *arr = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//TrackResponse/TrackInfo/TrackSummary" error:nil];
NSArray *p = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//TrackResponse/TrackInfo" error:nil];
if ([p count]>0) {
    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in p) {
        for(int counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [[[resultElement nodesForXPath:@"TrackDetail" error:nil] objectAtIndex:counter] stringValue]);
            [self.arr1 setObject:[[[resultElement nodesForXPath:@"TrackDetail" error:nil] objectAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:@"det"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add a sample xml. Maybe for your case it's easier to use the built in xml parser than to use a 3rd party library (I talk from experience ^^); see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7295767/207616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *p = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//TrackResponse/TrackInfo" error:nil];
if ([p count]>0) {
    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in [[p objectAtIndex:0] elementsForName:@"TrackDetail"]) {
          [array addObject:[resultElement stringValue]];
        }
    }
}
```

Not able to test it but it's similar to some code I've used before.

Comment: This logs them all, but since there is more than 1 how would I get all their values so I could put each of them in, for example, a label? Maybe put them in an array?

Comment: Edited the answer to create an array. You can then use the array to do whatever you want...