# Unable to parser using TouchXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am unable to parse response recieve using Touch XML My response from SOAP

```
    <CXMLDocument 0x4b30110 [0x4b34c90]> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetImagesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetImagesResult>;http://www.google.com;http://www.hotmail.com;http://www.yahoo.com</GetImagesResult>
    </GetImagesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

///  Touch XML function

```
    -(void) grabRSSFeed:(NSData *)responseData {

    // Initialize the blogEntries MutableArray that we declared in the header
    self.rssEntries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    // Create a new rssParser object based on the TouchXML "CXMLDocument" class, this is the
    // object that actually grabs and processes the RSS data

    CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
    //CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"rssParser %@",rssParser);
    //NSLog(@"url %@",url);

    // Create a new Array object to be used with the looping of the results from the rssParser
    NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;

    // Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
    resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//GetImagesResult" error:nil];

    // Loop through the resultNodes to access each items actual data
    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {

        // Create a temporary MutableDictionary to store the items fields in, which will eventually end up in blogEntries
        NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

        // Create a counter variable as type "int"
        int counter;

        // Loop through the children of the current  node
        for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {

            //[resultElement initWithXMLString:@""];
            NSString *strValue = [[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];
            //strValue = [strValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
            NSString *strName = [[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name];

            if ([resultNodes containsObject:@""] || resultNodes == nil || resultElement == nil || [resultElement isEqual:@""] || [resultElement children] == nil) {

                NSLog(@"Null Object");
            }
            else {

                if (strValue && strName) {

                    // Add each field to the blogItem Dictionary with the node name as key and node value as the value
                    [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.
        [self.rssEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]];

        NSLog(@"RSS Entries %@",self.rssEntries);
    }

    [[rssParser retain] release];
}
```

Comment: What exactly the problem is?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being "unable to parse response" is a very vague description of your problem. However, at first glance I noticed that this XPath query...

```
resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//GetImagesResult" error:nil];
```

...is most likely not matching any elements and thus returning an empty array.

Why? [Your XML has a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526887/getting-the-value-of-an-element-in-cocoa-using-touchxml). Use `nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:` method instead of `nodesForXPath:error:`. The former has an extra parameter that lets you provide a namespace mapping dictionary. Then edit your XPath query accordingly. See the example below:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"http://tempuri.org/",
                      @"tempuri", 
                      nil];

// Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//tempuri:GetImagesResult" namespaceMappings:dict error:nil];
```

---

Also, the last statement of the method is nonsense:

```
[[rssParser retain] release];
```

To balance the alloc-init, it should be:

```
[rssParser release];
```

Comment: Hi @albertamg, Now I cam across a new problem , before the response was in string so I successfully fetched it and now the response is in xsd schema

Comment: @user366584 I would suggest you to post a new question with the details of this new problem you are facing.